# How to add label inside ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, label, uilabel, xcode5

I am a newbie to Xcode 5 and Objective C. I want to develop word processing app. Still, I can't figure how to do it with Xcode.

How do I add label inside `ScrollView` with swipe left to right direction: left to preview, right to next word?

How do I add 100 words to a `UIlabel` in Xcode?

For example, swiping right for next word, "Apple", then swiping right again for next word "Bananas"; Swiping left to preview: "Apple".

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Here is below code that I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

//scrollVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface scrollVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroll;

@end
```

//scrollVC.m

```
#import "scrollVC.h"

@interface scrollVC ()

@end

@implementation scrollVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    [self.mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, 995)];
    [self.mainScroll setPagingEnabled:YES];

    UILabel *testLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 100, 100, 44)];
    [testLabel1 setText:@"testLabel1"];
    [testLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:testLabel1];

    UILabel *testLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(660, 100, 100, 44)];
    [testLabel2 setText:@"testLabel2"];
    [testLabel2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:testLabel2];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of UIScrollView paging. Here you can find [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html).

How can you add UILabel ( in general any instance on UIView ) to UIScrollView.

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; // replace default scroll with paging
for ( int i = 0; i < mWordsCount; i++ )
{
    UILabel* textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width * i, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    textLabel.text = @"currnet word"; // wordsArray[i]; or [wordsArray objectAtIndex:i]; 

    [scrollView addSubview:textLabel];
    // Uncomment if you don't use ARC
    //[textLabel release];
}
```